# Attaching CGPDFPageRef to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, nsdata, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to email a page of a PDF.

Here is what I have tried:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef SourcePDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"]]); // Create the CGPDFDocument from the URL
if (SourcePDFDocument == NULL) {
    return nil;
}

CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, pageNumber);
CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(SourcePDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
NSData *outputData;
CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)outputData);
CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
CGContextBeginPage(context, &mediaBox);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, SourcePDFPage);
CGContextEndPage(context);
CGDataConsumerRelease(consumer);
CGContextRelease(context);

NSString *emailSubject = @"Subject";
NSString *messageBody = @"message";

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailSubject];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc addAttachmentData:outputData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"thePage.pdf"];

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But it fails, when the email is received there is no attached file

I am also getting this error

[image: error]

Comment: You are not doing what is shown in the answer. You need to use and create an `NSMutableData` instance. Right now you have a `nil`, immutable `NSData` object.

Comment: It is the same result either way.

Comment: So you are saying that changing `outputData` to `NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData data];` doesn't work?